# How to Load and Apply a Cube Map with DDS Texture Loader?

Tags: c++, textures, directx, rendering, cubemap

So I have been spending a lot of time recently implementing a working skybox/skysphere, and have almost completed it. The last thing that I need to do is to load my given texture, a skybox texture consisting of 6 equal images, as a cube map and not a normal texture like I have been doing.

**- IGNORE FOLLOWING AND SKIP DOWN TO UPDATE -**

As you can see from the following image, the skybox texture is being loaded as a normal 2D texture and therefore gets warped by my HLSL effect as it should be. I also noticed that when I enable my vertex buffer, I get no visual output except for the default clear color (light blue). The picture taken below is rendered *without* my vertex buffer activated, and only my index buffer working. Also notable that this texture is being applied to a sphere currently, but I plan to move to a box once I get this working.

*IMAGE REMOVED*

I load the sky texture in with the following function.

```
ID3D11Texture2D* texture;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* shaderResView;

// ...

CreateDDSTextureFromFileEx(device, pathToTexture, 0, D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT, D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE, 0, D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE, false, (ID3D11Resource**)&texture, &shaderResView, nullptr);
```

My skybox render function is below. I also added some header code if you are curious.

```
////////////////////
// In header file //

struct Vertex
{
    Vertex() {}
    Vertex(float x, float y, float z,
        float u, float v,
        float nx, float ny, float nz)
        : pos(x, y, z), tex(u, v), nor(nx, ny, nz) {}

    XMFLOAT3 pos;
    XMFLOAT2 tex;
    XMFLOAT3 nor;
};

struct SKY
{
    XMMATRIX WVP;
    XMMATRIX World;
};

// In header file //
////////////////////

XMMATRIX scale, trans;
sky = XMMatrixIdentity();

// 'cpos' is the camera position vector.
scale = XMMatrixScaling(2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
trans = XMMatrixTranslation(XMVectorGetX(cpos), XMVectorGetY(cpos), XMVectorGetZ(cpos));
sky = scale * trans;

XMMATRIX WVP;
UINT s = sizeof(Vertex);
UINT o = 0;

dc->IASetIndexBuffer(sib, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
//dc->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &svb, &s, &o);

// NOTICE: The vertex buffer is commented out here, which
// produces the effect as seen in the screenshot of this
// post. When rendering without commenting it out, the only
// display output is of the background color.

WVP = sky * view * proj;
SKYOBJ.WVP = XMMatrixTranspose(WVP);
SKYOBJ.World = XMMatrixTranspose(sky);
dc->UpdateSubresource(SKYOBJBUFFER, 0, NULL, &SKYOBJ, 0, 0);
dc->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &SKYOBJBUFFER);
dc->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &srv);
dc->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &ss);

dc->VSSetShader(vs, 0, 0);
dc->PSSetShader(ps, 0, 0);
dc->OMSetDepthStencilState(dss, 0);
dc->RSSetState(rs);
dc->DrawIndexed(faces * 3, 0, 0);

return;
```

**UPDATE:**
So after quite a bit of playing around, I managed to pull off a working skysphere with almost a working texture. The following pictures are of the current result.
[image: New Result 1][image: New Result 2]

From the above images, you can clearly see that I produced a working sphere/box, and all that is left to do is load the texture in as a texture cube, not a plain texture. The following is my current texture loading function, which I thought would do the job. (Obviously doesn't).

```
ID3D11Texture2D* texture;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* shaderResView;

// ...

hr = CreateDDSTextureFromFileEx(
    device,
    pathToTexture,
    0,
    D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT,
    D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE,
    0,
    D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE,  // I'm guessing this is wrong/no effect.
    false,
    (ID3D11Resource**)&texture,
    &shaderResView,
    nullptr);
```

And here is my vertex and pixel shader for the skybox itself. (Put here in case I am missing something crucial.)

```
SamplerState ss;
TextureCube skyMap;

cbuffer SKY
{
    float4x4 WVP;
    float4x4 World;
};

struct vIn
{
    float3 pos : POSITION;
};

struct pIn
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 tex : TEXCOORD;
};

pIn vmain(vIn i)
{
    pIn o = (pIn)0;

    o.pos = mul(float4(i.pos, 1.0f), WVP).xyww;  // Disable Z
    o.tex = i.pos;

    return o;
}

float4 pmain(pIn i) : SV_TARGET
{
    return skyMap.Sample(ss, i.tex);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A Cube Map is actually an array of six 2D textures, two for each axis (x, -x, y, -y, z, -z). The first thing we do when loading a cube map is tell D3D we will be loading a texture cube, by creating a `D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO` structure and setting its MiscFlags member with `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE`.

Then we will create a 2D texture from the file. This 2D texture will actually be an array now since we said we are loading a texture cube.

Next we get the description of our texture so we can create a resource view description that matches the texture we loaded in.

Now we will create the shader resource view description. We will say that this resource view is a texture cube, or an array of 2D textures, so when the pixel shader is texturing a pixel, it will know how to use the 3D coordinates we give it, which are used to find the texel on the texture cube. Remember a 2D texture uses (u, v) coordinates, well a 3D texture uses (u, v, w) coordinates.

And finally we create the resource view using the texture we loaded in from a file, the shader resource views description, and storing the shader resource view in smrv.

```
D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO loadSMInfo;
loadSMInfo.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE;

ID3D11Texture2D* SMTexture = 0;
hr = D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile(d3d11Device, L"skymap.dds", 
    &loadSMInfo, 0, (ID3D11Resource**)&SMTexture, 0);

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC SMTextureDesc;
SMTexture->GetDesc(&SMTextureDesc);

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SMViewDesc;
SMViewDesc.Format = SMTextureDesc.Format;
SMViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURECUBE;
SMViewDesc.TextureCube.MipLevels = SMTextureDesc.MipLevels;
SMViewDesc.TextureCube.MostDetailedMip = 0;

hr = d3d11Device->CreateShaderResourceView(SMTexture, &SMViewDesc, &smrv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't render a skybox as a "cubemap". You often render objects using a environment cubemap that matches the skybox, but the skybox itself is just rendered with a set of 2D textures.

On Direct3D Feature Level 10.0 or later hardware, you can use a Texture2D array with 6 faces as both a cubemap and with another shader as six individual faces.

The WIC loader only loads 2D textures. If you want to pre-create complex surfaces like 2D arrays, cubemaps, or volume maps you should use `DDS` files instead. The [texassemble](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texassemble) and [texconv](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texconv) tools can help with that.

Comment: Ok, so I realized that WIC will not work and moved on to DDS Texture Loader, with a new loading function that looks like this: `CreateDDSTextureFromFileEx(d, sky, 0, D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT, D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE, 0, D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE, false, (ID3D11Resource**)&skytex, &srv, nullptr);` Am I missing anything here? I still have the exact same result.